# Copy unique data from one table to another

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert

I have two tables. `Table A` is the main table, and `table B` an auxiliary table. Now i need to copy from `table B` to `table A` only the rows with a `aux_id` not present in `table A`

**table_A**

```
id |aux_id | firstname | lastname
```

**table_B**

```
 aux_id | firstname | lastname
```

What I am trying, but apparently without success.

```
INSERT INTO table_A(aux_id,firstname,lastname)(SELECT aux_id,firstname,lastname FROM table_B WHERE aux_id != aux_id);
```

I am getting : `INSERT 0 0`

This is wrong, because i am sure that I have new entries in table B.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many ways to do this (`left join`, `not exists`, `not in`).  If you are learning SQL, `NOT IN`, might be the easiest on first encounter:

```
INSERT INTO table_A(aux_id, firstname, lastname)
    SELECT aux_id, firstname, lastname
    FROM table_B
    WHERE b.aux_id NOT IN (SELECT a.aux_id FROM table_A a);
```

I should say that I much prefer `NOT EXISTS`:

```
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table_A a WHERE a.aux_id = b.aux_id);
```

The reason has to do with the handling of `NULL` values.  The `NOT EXISTS` does what you expect.  `NOT IN` never returns true if the subquery returns a `NULL` value.

Comment: it is a bit more efficient. SELECT 1 does not require postgresql to assign a result set, what SELECT * does. And since we only test whether there are any results, the effort to assign is worthless.