# SQL: copy new values from one SQL table to another

Tags: sql

I am trying to copy values from one SQL table to another. The problem I have is that some of the values already exists in both tables and I only want to copy unique values. The below code should show what I ideally want (but which doesn't work).

```
INSERT INTO newTable (column1, column2, column3,ID)
    SELECT column1, column2, column3,ID
    FROM oldTable 
    WHERE Newtable.ID <> oldTable.ID
```

Can someone present a solution that works? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's your dbms

Comment: You can even find this helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33630451/copy-unique-data-from-one-table-to-another

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use `NOT exists` on where clause.

```
INSERT INTO newtable 
            (column1, 
             column2, 
             column3, 
             id) 
SELECT column1, 
       column2, 
       column3, 
       id 
FROM   oldtable o 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
               FROM   newtable t 
               WHERE  t.id = o.id);
```

[SQL-Server SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/fa703/1)

[My-sql SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fa7035/2)

[Oracle SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fa703/1)

Comment: The EXISTS versions doesn't work if newtable has more than 1 row.

Comment: @jarlh you are right I have edited my answer. thank for your point out.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL server 2008+ you can use an except statement:

```
INSERT INTO newTable
(
    column1,
    column2,
    column3,
    ID
)
SELECT column1,
       column2,
       column3,
       ID
FROM oldTable
EXCEPT
SELECT column1,
       column2,
       column3,
       ID
FROM newTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the number of records you're dealing with.

[This guy has benchmarked](http://cc.davelozinski.com/sql/fastest-way-to-insert-new-records-where-one-doesnt-already-exist) all the different ways of doing it. Which way is "better" depends on the number of records.

Also, if this is an ongoing process, you'll be better off with an INSERT trigger so you can just add the new records when they happen instead of needing to query the whole table every time.